# Weird Scala behavior when defining simple Stream

Tags: scala

Why 6? I'd like to define sequence (5, 6, ...). How to do it correctly using "val" not "def"?

```
scala> val f: Stream[Int] = 5 #:: f map { _ + 1 }
f: Stream[Int] = Stream(6, ?)
```

I'm using scala 2.9.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some parentheses to tell it to apply the `map` to `f`, but not to the 5:

```
scala> val f: Stream[Int] = 5 #:: (f map { _ + 1 })
f: Stream[Int] = Stream(5, ?)

scala> f.take(5).toList
res2: List[Int] = List(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I must be blind ;-)